# Access 2003 - Pass Through Queries, Query Definitions and Form.Recordset (Oh My)

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc, jet

I am creating a pass through union query using an ODBC data source and trying to open the recordset with `form!Formname.Recordset = qdf.opernRecordset`. The query executes properly and returns the expected data, but when I go to execute the above code I get the error:

`Error 3251 Operation is not supported for this type of object.`

I know that help,concerning this error, states:

`Some operations are also not supported, depending on if you are accessing a Microsoft Jet or an ODBC data source.`

What is this error caused by and what is a potential workaround?

Comment: What happens when you just set the form record source to that query in design view?

Comment: @HelloW Can you do that with a pass-through that has parameters?

Comment: Yes you can, of course this is useless for production but for testing I would recommend it.

Comment: @hellow How would you go about doing that? Using a saved query doesn't allow for the passing of parameters and putting the query into the Data > RecordSource fails due to a lack of parameter provisioning. By ODBC tables, I don't mean linked Table Objects.

Comment: I have experience in SQL Server Stored procedures and pass through queries.  Is that what you are working with?

Comment: What happens if you use `Set`? ... `Set form!Formname.Recordset = qdf.OpenRecordset`

Comment: @HansUp hmm now why didn't I think of that?

Comment: @HansUp , @HelloW, it's disappointing that `set` worked. 

Thanks!

Comment: @Elias Why is that disappointing?  :-)

Comment: @HansUp, was just about to ask how you handled it that way. Thanks (again) for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VBA, use the equal sign to assign a value to a simple variable:

```vb
MyText = "foo"
```

But use the `Set` keyword when assigning to an object variable.  In your case, the form's `Recordset` is a property rather than a variable, but that property is an object, so you still need `Set`:

```vb
Set form!Formname.Recordset = qdf.OpenRecordset
```